# MongoDB: Any possibility to show operation progress of insertMany using C/C++ drivers?

Tags: mongodb

In my Qt-based app I've started using MongoDB via C driver (C++ driver happens to require more configuration efforts and is documented not as good as C driver). One thing I cannot figure out is if it is possible to track the progress of a current time-consuming operation like `mongoc_collection_insert_many()`.

Suppose I make a client connection to a remote mongoDB server, and insert 5000 documents into a collection (which, by the way, I do in a separate thread to avoid blocking the GUI-part). In my case this operation takes 1-2 minutes, depending on the network load. For sure, I can track insertion progress if I use `mongoc_collection_insert_one()` instead and cycle over documents, but this then takes about 15 minutes which is unacceptable for me. Is it possible to track the progress with `mongoc_collection_insert_many()`? If not, is it possible in C++ driver? (asking just 'in case', as I guess it doesn't depend on drivers at all.)

Comment: You could do it in large enough chunks to maintain efficiency, but small enough to not take more than a few seconds. Like something in the 100-500 range.

Comment: It came to my mind as well, but this will make the entire operation slower in any case, compared to unfragmented insertMany, which is undesirable. If no better solution exists, this might be a workaround.